# How do I validate these columns?

Tags: sql, sql-server, validation

I'm working on a database and I need to validate some columns under the Payment schema.

Like if a credit card is not used for payments, CreditCardNumber, CardHoldersName, and CreditCardExpDate should be made NULL. If a credit card is used, the CreditCardExpDate value should be greater than the PaymentDate
PaymentDue can allow NULL but should not be greater than PaymentAmount

I've searched online but what I get are complex triggers and procedures which are not really helpful.

```
  create table Payment.Payments(
  Payment_ID int identity (200, 21),
  Payment_Amount money constraint chk_Payment_Amount check (Payment_Amount > 
  '0'),
  Payment_Date date, -- is to be greater than the end date which is on another table
  Credit_Card_Number int,
  Card_Holders_Name char (50),
  Credit_Card_Expiry_Date date, 
  Project_ID int Foreign Key references ProjectDetails.Projects(Project_ID),
  Payment_Due money -- should not be greater than Payment Amount but 
  can still accept null*
   );
```

The notes show the current validation problem i'm having.

I created a trigger for the payment_date but i can only get it to fire when the inserted date is greater than the current date, i need it to fire if it is less than the end date(end date is on another table)

CREATE TRIGGER paymentdate
    ON Payment.Payments
    FOR INSERT
    AS
      DECLARE @ModifiedDate date
      SELECT @ModifiedDate = Payment_Date FROM Inserted
          IF (@ModifiedDate > getdate())
          BEGIN
            PRINT 'The modified date should be the current date. Hence, cannot insert.'
            ROLLBACK TRANSACTION
          END

Comment: Please provide sample data and an explanation -- using the data -- of what is allowed and not allowed.  In a "payments" table, aren't all credit cards used for payments?

Comment: Sounds like you're describing a `CONSTRAINT`.

Comment: the datatype `int` for a creditcard number is a bit of an oxymoron. The maximum value for an `int` is 2,147,483,647 and a card number is made up of 4 sets of 4 digit numbers (i.e. `9999 9999 9999 9999`). Even as a number, that's far higher than the max value of an `int`. I'd suggest using a `char(19)` and making a constraint on the format as well.

Comment: Think long and hard about your schema. There is a difference between "payment" and "invoice" (or whatever entity name you want to use for the obligation that requires a payment). A schema just for payments also seems to be overkill.

Comment: I would implement such things in application business layer, it is much better to do it there until and unless you are doing this for practice.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm reading a lot between the lines here, but I *think* this is what you're after (Note I have used the `dbo` schema though):

```
USE Sandbox;
GO

CREATE TABLE dbo.Payments (
    Payment_ID int identity(200, 21),
    Payment_Amount money CONSTRAINT chk_Payment_Amount CHECK (Payment_Amount > '0'),
    Payment_Date date,
    Credit_Card_Number char(19), --note datatype change from int to char. See my comment below (copied from my comment)
    Card_Holders_Name varchar (50), --note I've used varchar instead. Names aren't all 50 characters long
    Credit_Card_Expiry_Date date,
    --Project_ID int FOREIGN KEY REFERENCES ProjectDetails.Projects(Project_ID) --Commented out as I don't have this table
    Payment_Due money CONSTRAINT chk_Payment_Due CHECK (Payment_Due > '0' OR Payment_Due IS NULL)
    );
GO

--Credit Card format validation
ALTER TABLE dbo.Payments ADD CONSTRAINT ck_Credit_Card CHECK (Credit_Card_Number LIKE '[0-9][0-9][0-9][0-9] [0-9][0-9][0-9][0-9] [0-9][0-9][0-9][0-9] [0-9][0-9][0-9][0-9]' OR Credit_Card_Number IS NULL);

--Add card details must be there, or none.
ALTER TABLE dbo.Payments ADD CONSTRAINT ck_Card_Details CHECK ((Credit_Card_Number IS NULL AND Card_Holders_Name IS NULL AND Credit_Card_Expiry_Date IS NULL)
                                                           OR  (Credit_Card_Number IS NOT NULL AND Card_Holders_Name IS NOT NULL AND Credit_Card_Expiry_Date IS NOT NULL))

GO
DROP TABLE dbo.Payments;
```

*Comment made on the Card Number's datatype:*

The datatype `int` for a credit card number is a bit of an oxymoron. The maximum value for an `int` is 2,147,483,647 and a card number is made up of 4 sets of 4 digit numbers (i.e. `9999 9999 9999 9999`). Even as a number, that's far higher than the max value of an `int`. I'd suggest using a `char(19)` and making a constraint on the format as well.

Comment: Thanks a lot. I'll try it and get back to you

Comment: it worked. Thanks a lot. But i hit another road block, still trying to solve it. The PaymentDate should be greater than the end date of the project. The problem now is that the enddate is from another table. I'm trying to see if i can  build a constraint that would do that. Sounds like something i;ll have to do with a function @Larnu